# Rangy highlighter deserialized issue

Tags: rangy

I had highlighted HTML content using rangy highlighter module which has content as

```
<strong>Hello</strong> test rangy highlighter
```

when i highlight the above text and deserialize it creates two span as

```
<strong><span class="highlighter">Hello</span></strong><span class="highlighter"> test rangy highlighter</span>
```

Instead of above can we have single span as

```
<span class="highlighter"><strong>Hello</strong>test rangy highlighter</span>
```

can any one help me to resolve this issue.